# How to fix setTimeout behavior over HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

On my client app, I'm using Socket IO to check for unread events. I make a request to my backend, which sets a timeout of 5 seconds, then proceeds to check for unread events and sends any back.

```
// client
socket.on("response", ({ mostRecentMessages }) => {
    // do some stuff first
    socket.emit("listenForNew", { userId, currentMessagesFromEveryone });
})
```

```
// backend
  socket.on("listenForNew", ({ userId, currentMessagesFromEveryone }) => {
    if (currentMessagesFromEveryone && userId) {
      const { MostRecentMessages } = require("./constants/models");

      const filteredIds = [];

      currentMessagesFromEveryone.forEach(message => {
        filteredIds.push(message.conversation._id);
      });

      console.log("Entered!");

      setTimeout(async () => {
        const mostRecentMessages = await MostRecentMessages.find({
          to: userId,
          date: { $gt: connectedUsersAllMessages[userId].timeIn },
          conversation: { $nin: filteredIds }
        }).populate("to from conversation");

        allMessagesSocket.sockets.connected[
          connectedUsersAllMessages[userId].socketId
        ].emit("response", {
          mostRecentMessages
        });
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
```

At first, it works fine. It prints `Entered!` one time for about 4, 5 requests. Then on the 6th, it starts to print `Entered!` twice.

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with `setTimeout` (in the title)?

Comment: It'a hard to get a full answer with partial code (the client `setTimeout` call). For instance.. why not choosing `setInterval` instead?

Comment: My bad, I edited the code

Comment: @ymz That's a fair point, I haven't tried that. But why am I getting such behavior with setTimeout?

Comment: @MikeK - It's not **the** problem, but **a** problem is that you're passing an `async` function into `setTimeout` and you don't have the entirety of that function in a `try`/`catch`. That means the function can reject. `setTimeout` doesn't use the promise the function returns, and in particular doesn't handle rejections, meaning rejections will turn into unhandled rejections. Those are a Bad Thing™. :-) Also, `setTimeout` usually expects a second argument (the milliseconds to wait). It's not [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) as optional.

Comment: Update the question with you code.. there are couple of strategies to make `setTimeout` to invoke every X seconds and I'm afraid that you may created a race condition there. Again.. wit a more detailed code there will be a more detailed answer :)

Comment: @ymz I've made an update to the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand, but after about 10 rounds there and back, it starts to log 3 `Entered!`s. I'm not sure why this is happening, because, like you said, the client waits for a response before making a new one

Comment: @MikeK - In your *latest* code update, the output of `Entered!` isn't even in the timer callback, so the timer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: So my issue has nothing to do with the timeout?

Comment: @MikeK - With the code as it is in the question right now as I write this, I can't see how it can be, no.

Comment: is there any other place where you are emitting "listenForNew" from client other than from "onResponse"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in favor of the below approach:

- Wait for X seconds (5 in our use case)
- Call an async operation (execution time in unknown)
- Wait until async execution complete
- Wait for another X seconds before executing the next call

Implementation may be something like that:

```
const interval = 5000;

function next() {
  setTimeout(async () => myAsyncOperation(), interval);
}

function myAsyncOperation() {
   const mostRecentMessages = await MostRecentMessages.find({
      to: userId,
      date: { $gt: connectedUsersAllMessages[userId].timeIn },
      conversation: { $nin: filteredIds }
    }).populate("to from conversation");

    allMessagesSocket.sockets.connected[
      connectedUsersAllMessages[userId].socketId
    ].emit("response", () => {
      mostRecentMessages();
      next(); // "next" function call should be invoked only after "mostRecentMessages" execution is completed (or a race condition may be applied)
    }); 
}

next();
```

I haven't compiled this code but I hope that the concept is clear